# Is it possible to port bootstrap templates from Wordpress to Django?

Tags: django, wordpress, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I want to port a couple of WP boostrap themes to django, the question is how? is there a straight-forward way (since both are made with bootstrap) or it takes too much work and its easier to build a similar theme from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is framework-agnostic. You'll just have to copy over the files and get to work. You might have an easier time using [Django-CMS](http://django-cms.org/) to build out your site, since it will give you things you'd expect to find in WordPress, but there isn't a 1:1 equivalent.

Comment: No prob its for a landing/portfolio theme, not too much to code. Btw you dont happen to know of some documentation about this? something to use in case I get stuck. Thanks

Comment: Documentation in regards to...?

Comment: Porting a template to django?